# Is there a way to know is jdbc connection given by hikari is a "new one" or a "recycled one"

Tags: java, hikaricp

I am using HikariCP in my webapp. I would like to know if there is a way to know if the connection given by the pool (getConnection() ...) is a new one or a recycled one?
Why? Because just after the "getConnection()", I do some kind of "alter session". And I don't want to do it again if it's a recycled connection, because the job is already done.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. Also, according to the JDBC specification, a user should treat a logical connection obtained from a data source backed by a connection pool exactly the same as if it was a new physical connection. That simplifies the mental model, and it allows connection pools to do additional housekeeping, like resetting connection state, etc.

If you want to do some initialization, you may want to consider using the HikariCP property `connectionInitSql`.